# Property Changed event within class

Tags: c#, class, events

I got a question about events within classes.

I have a whole load of properties within my class and want to fire an event whenever a property is changed. I want to use the changed properties to calculate a result.

One possible option might be adding a call to every single property-set but this is - for my understanding - too q'n'd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common approach to realise this would be to implement the      **INotitfyPropertyChanged** interface and raise the **PropertyChanged** event in every settter method for the properties where you need it.

Then you implement an event handler which reacts to the event and performs the operations needed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks K.J. But (as far as I see) doesn't this require to call the PropertyChanged Event in every single property? I was looking for some generic way without the need to do so. Or am I wrong?

Comment: As I wrote: this would be the common approach, since you seldom need to implement the notification on EVRY property, but only a selective choice. 

Here https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged you find a project which uses code injection at compile time using a class level attribute. I haven´t tested it yet, but this seems to be a good approach preventing to pollute your properties with alle the event calls :)

Comment: Well ok, not what I expected but something I'll have a look at. Thanks a lot :)